# difference between method and procedure in java

Tags: java

is there a difference between a method and a procedure in java or every thing is just a method?
if there is a difference, can I have an example ?

Comment: What's the difference between a car and an automobile?

Comment: Java, C#, and many other OO languages have methods. FORTRAN, Pascal, Basic and many other imperative languages have functions and procedures. The core concept remains the same, as they all represent executable code.

Comment: In PASCAL procedure was method which didn't return any value, function was method which returned value. In Java we don't distinguish them, procedures and functions are simply called methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has the concept of a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) from the database world, but that's a specific concept.

If you're talking about the generic term *procedure*, then there is no difference between a method and a procedure. You'll often see the terms function, method, and procedure used pretty much interchangeably, but *method* is the technically correct term in Java, since it is an object-oriented language. (Methods are functions that belong to a class or an object.)